# How can I vertically offset child element from the center of its parent?

Tags: css

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zS7yK/2/) is a jsFiddle I set up.

The parent and child element's height will be uncertain(means it will change after) and the child element's position must be absolute.

How can I offset the child element vertically by five pixels from the center of the parent?

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    background:lightgray;
    height:50px;/*parent's height will change after*/
    width:200px;
}
.parent .child{
    position:absolute; /* needs to be absolutely position */
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;/*child's height will change after*/
    background:darkgray;
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? What do you mean by "offset 5px"? Also, do you want to use JavaScript?

Comment: There would be no visual difference since the child is 100% of the parent.

Comment: Offset 5px from where? top? bottom? sides? according to your example the child element is aligned vectically to the middle as you need it to be...

Comment: @Rob W i want the child dom offset 5px from the middle and only use css~

Comment: @Defims: We've established that already. In what direction should it be offset? And I think you're using the term [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) incorrectly.

Comment: @Yaniro from the middle,yes ,i want to offset from the middle with two precondition.

Comment: @Pumou maybe i can change an expression:
i want to achieve top:50%-childdom's height+offset;and the parent and child dom's height will change,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

offset 5px where??

Like this ----> [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zS7yK/2/)

or

Like this ----> [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zS7yK/4/)

Comment: sorry for my unclear expression, i mean offset from middle vertical direction.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, then you want to offset the child by five pixels vertically. I'm not sure whether this means the element should move up or down from the middle of the parent, but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/L3mzy/) is an example of it moving up and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/L3mzy/2/) is one for moving it down.

Here's the code I added to the child's CSS to move it up:

```
top:50%;
margin-top:-15px;
```

Also remove the current `top` and `bottom` declarations for the child.

We set it 50% from the top of the parent and then subtract half of its height from its top offset which centers it. We add (or subtract) 5 pixels to/from that offset to offset it further.

For variable height, use this CSS (this moves it up five pixels):

```
top:-5px;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/L3mzy/3/).

Comment: oh ,thanks Purmou,but i lost another precondition,the child's height is also uncertain.

Comment: if the child's height is also uncertain,i willnot get the half of chid's height,and the child element's top|padding-top|border-top's percent value base on parent not child element,so ,i don't know how to get it with css~

Answer (score 1):

Use `border-top`
See my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zS7yK/11/) here

- with top:0;bottom:0; and margin:auto; child element can align middle when parent and child element's height "uncertain";
- border-top:10px; can make child element offset.

and maybe you'll solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Considering the element is centered, you can just add

```
transform(translateY: 5px)
```

to offset the div vertically, or

```
transform(translateX: 5px)
```

to offset it horizontally.